# How do you set the Dock Icon of a Java program?

Tags: java

I keep getting pointed to

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
```

but that package doesn't exist on apple's website. Is there a new way?

Comment: i think this is the right approach but it looks like the links have moved
[Java Development Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The class you seek is part of a Maven artifact, namely [`com.apple.AppleJavaExtensions`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.4). Either use Maven in your build, or just download the JAR of the artifact and add it to your build path--this artifact itself has no dependencies.